# Ajax request will freeze my Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/start_images_stream',
    type: "GET",
    data : { image_id: tst },
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function (data_response) {
        status = data_response.responseText; 
        console.log("The response was: "+status);
        stream_images();
    }
});
```

this seems to freeze my javascript. It stays stuck on the ajax request and does not move on to stream_images().

On my server I got this:

```
  def start_images_stream

  #ajax request parameters
  tst=params[:image_id]

  start_method

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => "OK"}
  end 

  end
```

The 'start_method' has a loop..do, which never ends! I understand that might be the problem. So I changed my ajax request to a POST one:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/start_images_stream',
    type: "POST",
    data : { image_id: tst },
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function () {
        stream_images();
    }
});
```

and adapted my server code to it. Now the ajax request seems to freeze my main thread again.
I just want to say to the server, start 'function a' produce an unlimited number of images and that's it. Then Javascript reads the files and lists them on the HTML page.

It doesn't seem to work

Comment: So if you add code right outside the $.ajax block, that code doesn't get called while your Ajax request is processing?  I just want to make sure your thread really is getting frozen... Also, have you tried changing the program at the server side so it just returns a simple string, to eliminate any algorithmic problems from that side?

Comment: ok I am going to try ur idea

Comment: yes it works if I place it outside. thanks. just a last question, does the ajax request continues to execute ?

Comment: The Ajax request continues to execute, but it will time out after a while (the time out period depends on your server configuration).  This is why you have to put code in a callback because the request runs Asynchronously (in the background).

Answer (score 3):

i think your complete function:

```
complete: function () {
        stream_images();
    }
```

should be in the success property to work, just like that:

```
success: function () {
        stream_images();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
status = data_response;
```

The callback passes the result as its argument (the string or an object if json was specified), it doesn't have a `responseText` property.

jQuery abstracts those kind of stuff, so you don't have to worry about knowing the `responseText` property, you just get the result.